# Restoring iOS apps (+data) that weren't transfered to PC before iPhone backup

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore, filesystem

I recently performed a backup of my iPhone, but forgot to transfer my purchases to my PC before restoring from the backup. A couple apps had some data I'd really hate to lose. To make things worse, the backup is apparently corrupted, and the only solution seems to be paying 30$ for a program that can repair it.

If I were to pay to have it repaired, will I be able to recover all the app data from what was installed at the time the backup was performed? Can I just download the apps in question to my iTunes library, and the backup will have the appropriate data to restore to my iPhone?

Hopefully someone has precise info on this; it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full disclosure: I'm the lead developer of the repair software you're most likely referring to ;)

The data for the apps are stored in the backups, just not the apps themselves. Normally, the apps should be downloaded again automatically from the app store after you restore and setup (logging in to your app store account/AppleID). You don't have to have the apps themselves transferred into iTunes in order for their data to be in the backup.

So yes, normally if you repair it, the apps should reinstall, and the data for those apps should be there waiting after the restore. In the rare event (but does happen) that the app data that you need was part of what was broken in the backup, that's why we offer a guarantee with our software :)